# Getting an error on writing a DB output value to a variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

The syntax I used is `props.put("perpetual_id",vars.get("Inventory_id_1"));`

```
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``props.put("perpetual_id",vars.get("Inventory_id_1")); System.out.println(vars.ge . . . '' : Method Invocation props.put
```

If I am using `System.out.println(vars.get("inventoryId_1"));`, it's printing fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a typo, i.e. missing underscore in your `props.put...` statement.

Given `System.out.println(vars.get("inventoryId_1"));` works fine my expectation is that you need to change your line to something like:

```
props.put("perpetual_id",vars.get("inventoryId_1"));
```

Few more hints:

- you can use [bsh.shared namespaces](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) as an alternative to JMeter Properties
- you can get more human-friendly error message by putting your Beanshell code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

  ```
  try { 
      //your code here
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Error in beanshell", ex);
      throw ex;
  }
  ```

  This way you can get the "usual" stacktrace printed to *jmeter.log* file which will be way more informative and will help you to get to the bottom of the issue much faster and easier.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Dmitri, actually my syntax here had a typo (apologies for confusion), and I had tried below syntax only. props.put("perpetual_id",vars.get("inventoryId_1")); Still got the same error.

Comment: what is in *jmeter.log*?

Comment: There is a NPE in bean shell

Comment: ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Error in beanshell java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh